# GLM Poisson thinks I have negative values in my dataset, throws error

Tags: glm, poisson

I am trying to do a poisson GLM, and yet I continue to get this error

```
Poisson1 <- glm(Number.Flowers ~ Site, data = Flowering2, family="poisson")

Error in eval(family$initialize) :negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family
```

My data is count data and so is all positive values and zeros. What could be going on?

Is it possible for my CSV file to contain hidden negative values?

Comment: If you provide you CSV file it would be tremendously easier to determine if it contains any hidden negative values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your CSV might be flawed in some way. Try a different method of importing it into R (fread, read.table, etc). Check for NA or NaN issues. Compare the number of rows.